# Regular glyphicons usage in html

Tags: html, css, glyphicons

I'm trying to use glyphicons from glyphicons(dot)com but I couldn't find out how to use them in my code... Should I make some kind of css file (like it's done in bootstrap) or should I link it somehow into my html? 
I hope someone knows the answer :) Thanks!

```
<li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicons-44-group"></span> Clans </a></li>
```

If it helps, this is e.g one of my code where I want to use glyphicon (with glyphicon code). 
Btw, path is "glyph/glyph/glyph/png"

Comment: you have to link the library you want t use in your html file

Comment: O.k, but I'm not sure how to do it. Tried some ways but failed

Comment: Include this on the head of your html file: `<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: You can't use the glyphicons free set on your website as they're PNG files. If you want to use them in websites you need the svg files.

Comment: Troyer, those are bootstrap glyphicons I assume. I need usage of glyphicons downloaded from glyphicon website.

Comment: Rishav, do you know why is that so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **[GLYPHICONS](http://glyphicons.com/)** use. You need to buy [License](http://glyphicons.com/license/) or use free. If you want to free then you will get small

> GLYPHICONS Basic set

`.png` icons.

Examples of use

`<img src="path/glyphicons-11-envelope.png" alt="glyphicons envelope icon" height="16" width="24" />`

All License

> GLYPHICONS Basic set
>
> GLYPHICONS Halflings
>
> GLYPHICONS Filetypes
>
> GLYPHICONS Social
>
> All sets in raster files*
>
> Commercial use**

Examples of use

`<img src="path/glyphicons-11-envelope.png" alt="glyphicons envelope icon" height="16" width="24" />`

PRO License

> GLYPHICONS Basic set
>
> GLYPHICONS Halflings
>
> GLYPHICONS Filetypes
>
> GLYPHICONS Social
>
> All sets in raster files*
>
> All sets in vector files
>
> All sets as a web font
>
> All sets in live HTML/CSS
>
> Future updates for free
>
> Commercial use**

Examples of use

`<img src="path/glyphicons-11-envelope.png" alt="glyphicons envelope icon" height="16" width="24" />
/* Note: You can use @2x and @3x size. */`

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> /* This is for example */
```

Only free use [GLYPHICONS](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons) icon using `HTML/CSS` from [Twitter-Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons) file.

Examples of use

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

That's all know about the **GLYPHICON**.

Answer (score 3):

The icons you downloaded are PNGs, I think you should try this:

`<li><a href="#"><img src="YOUR_PATH"> Clans </a></li>`

Comment: Yea, I guess that's one and only way.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Boostrap then Glyphicons are already included, so there is no need to link them (providing you already have Bootstrap linked). However, if you are not using Bootstrap you can call just the Glyphicons like Troyer commented:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstra‌​p-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

You can then display Glyphicons on the page, like so:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
```

Notice the extra glyphicon class before the class for the specific icon.

If you need any more help, check out [this page.](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-how-to-use)

Comment: Firstly thanks for the correct answer :) And yes I have bootstrap installed and I have Bootstrap icons. But thing is that I need icons from glyphicons(dot)com and those are not supported in bootstrap.

Comment: Ah ok. I'm not sure if I can help you there as I haven't purchased them from there. Have you tried Syraxis' suggestion?

Comment: Yes, it's a solution at the moment :)

Answer (score -1):

First you want to give reference to same glyph library which you are using on your page than use span tag to put your glyph

Include this cdn link inside your head tag

```
 <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

then use your span tag to use glyphicon

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon name"></span>
```

Comment: That's bootstrap way. I got my glyphicons from glyphicons website and I don't think they're related.

Comment: Try using bootstrap cdn above

Comment: Just in case tried. Doesn't work. And I'm sure it's because bootstrap doesn't support these icons.

Comment: These glyph are in build in bootstrap,you can take reference from getbootstrap.com,download bootstrap files and try to include them

Comment: Can you please put all your files in fiddle and post here